# Clear form input field on toggle off

Tags: php, jquery

I have a form where I want an optional field to be cleared if the user changes his/her choice. I got the form to add or remove the optional option, but if the user type in text in the optional field, and then changes his/her mind, and hit the cancel button, then I want the value in the optional field to be cleared. I need this because when the form is submitted, it is important that the optional field is empty if no new date from the optional field is ment to be submitted to the database.

```
    <form>
      <a href="#" class="show_hide">+ Add New</a>
      <div class="slidingDiv">
        Artists name: <input type="text" name="name">
        Artists info: <textarea name="info" cols="65" rows="15"></textarea>  
        <a href="#" class="show_hide">Cancel</a>
      </div>
    </form>
```

-

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".slidingDiv").hide();
    $(".show_hide").show();

$('.show_hide').click(function(){
$(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
});
```

});

Comment: I cannot get what is the issue and the related question. Reproducing the code, gives really strange results, which makes your Q even less understandable. You use HIDE on a parent element and SHOW on a children one... isn't that strange enough? Hope I answered you Q in this comment BTW

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to add the link which adds the option. I also have two fields, which I guess complicates it and could be why a simple .val(''); doesn't do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.show_hide').click(function(){
    $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
    $(".slidingDiv input").val("");
    $(".slidingDiv textarea").val("");
    $(".slidingDiv textarea").html("")
});
```

This changes the value of the field to "", or blank.

Note: Textarea's in there twice because I believe some browsers don't record the textarea's content as a `value`, but as `innerHTML`.

Edit: If you want to clear a specific field, assign an `id` to that field in your HTML, and then just clear its value using jQuery.

For example:

```
<input type="text" name="customerName" id="myInputField" />
<textarea name="customerResponse" id="myTextarea" /></textarea>
```

...and then your jQuery:

```
$("#myInputField").val("");
$("#myTextarea").val("");
```

So if you gave `.slidingDiv input` the `id` "myInputField", and you just wanted to clear the input and NOT the textarea, then your jQuery would look like this:

```
$('.show_hide').click(function(){
    $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
    $("#myInputField").val("");
});
```

This is really, really, really basic jQuery, so make sure you look through some tutorials before coming to StackOverflow for help!

Comment: Thanks for the respond. It's not working for me. If I hit the add button again, the old text is still visable in the text field. Is it browser dependent?

Comment: Oh. That's because I'm a moron. The `.val("")` has to be attached to the element in which the user types their input. Editing the above now...

Comment: Ah! Thanks a lot! :D Now, one question, in this example I do not have any other text field outside the toggle section, butif I do, the text on the field below the toggle section is also cleared. Is there a way to identify what fields should be effected, so that other will not be cleared, only the ones in optional option? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot Robert, I see your point. I'll go back and read up on it better.